# Java : Sort a List<Point> with neighbour

Tags: java, list, sorting, point, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of Point and I want to sort them with their neighbour.

For exemple :
List init

```
(0,0); (1,0); (5,0); (6,0);  
(0,1); (1,1); (5,1); (6,1);
```

List sorted

```
(0,0); (1,0); (0,1); (1,1);  
(5,0); (6,0); (5,1); (6,1);
```

How can I do that ?

```
list.sort(new Comparator<Point>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        // Euclidian distance or something like that
        return ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify the sorting rules?  "Sort them with their neighbour" isn't very clear.

Comment: If the distance beetween 2 point is <2 it's a neighbour.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  What output do I expect if  my input is `(2,0); (1,0); (0,0); (1,1)` and why?

Comment: I don't see how a "if point <2 it's a neighbour" could be useful in a sort. maybe you want to filter it? Or you want to show all neightbour first and later all "normal"?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I am wondering whether melkir actually means "partition", instead of "sort".  I am suspicious of the way the points in the expected output in the question are organised onto two lines.  Maybe anything to do with comparators and sorting is not what he/she is looking for.

Comment: These points represent 2 objects in a binary image, the background is black and my objects are white. My initial list is the list of the white pixel.
I want to find their neighbors in order to do an image segmentation by using the distance between two Object with my ordered list.

With your exemple the order is not very important, they represent a single object cause they are neighbors.

Comment: melkir, perhaps you could edit the question to make it clear that it's not about sorting - it's about identifying these subsets of contiguous points.  Otherwise, more people might come and give you answers that relate to sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an algorithm that does this, starting with a set of points.

1. If there are no points in the set, then stop.
2. Make a new set (the current object), and choose any point out of the original set to be the first point in the new set.
3. Remove the chosen point from the set and add it to the current object.
4. Check each of the chosen point's eight neighbours to see if any are in the original set.
5. For any point thus found, run this algorithm starting from step 3 (use recursion for this).
6. If none of the neighbours were in the original set, go back to step 1.

Comment: Thank to you I have understand how the region-growing method works and how to implement it. Thank you David Wallace :)

Answer (score 2):

Implement Comparator to get the ordering you want.
Example:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Point>()
{
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        //Euclidean distance from 0,0
        Point origin = new Point();
        return Double.compare(p1.distance(origin), p2.distance(origin));
    }
});
```

or, with java 8 lambda expressions:

```
Collections.sort(list, ((p1, p2) -> Double.compare(p1.distance(0, 0), p2.distance(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in your class and use a Collection which orders elements using comparator, or use use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)